# Play Framework using AsyncCacheApi | Implement Cache for tests in Java

Tags: java, scala, caching, playframework

I'm currently trying to implements play.api.cache.AsyncCacheApi in Java. I am having heavy trouble to implement get and getOrElseUpdate because of the generic parameter.

My class:

```
package common;

import akka.Done;
import net.sf.ehcache.Element;
import play.api.cache.AsyncCacheApi;
import play.api.cache.SyncCacheApi;
import scala.Function0;
import scala.Option;
import scala.concurrent.Future;
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;
import scala.reflect.ClassTag;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import static scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters.toScala;

public class InMemoryCacheJava implements AsyncCacheApi {

   final Map<String, Element> cache = new HashMap<>();

   @Override
   public SyncCacheApi sync() {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public Future<Done> set(String key, Object value, Duration expiration) {
       return toScala(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
           () -> {
               final Element element = new Element(key, value);
               if (expiration == Duration.Zero()) {
                   element.setEternal(true);
               }
               element.setTimeToLive(Math.toIntExact(expiration.toSeconds()));
               cache.put(key, element);
               return Done.getInstance();
           }
       ));
   }

   @Override
   public Future<Done> remove(String key) {
       return toScala(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
           () -> {
               cache.remove(key);
               return Done.getInstance();
           }
       ));
   }

   @Override
   public <T> Future<Option<T>> get(String key, ClassTag<T> evidence$2) {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public Future<Done> removeAll() {
       return toScala(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
           () -> {
               cache.clear();
               return Done.getInstance();
           }
       ));
   }

   @Override
   public <A> Future<A> getOrElseUpdate(String key, Duration expiration, Function0<Future<A>> orElse, ClassTag<A> evidence$1) {
       return null;
   }

}
```

Is it the right way to do it ? I'm using this API because in my production code I am using the implementation DefaultAsyncCacheApi and I want to test my code with an internal cache (like a map). What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the Java API instead and I implemented my own in memory cache.

My working code (it might not be the best implementation), if it can help:

```
package common;

import akka.Done;
import play.cache.AsyncCacheApi;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

public class InMemoryCache implements AsyncCacheApi {
    private final HashMap<String, Object> cache = new HashMap();

    @Override
    public <T> CompletionStage<T> get(String key) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture((T) this.cache.get(key));
    }

    @Override
    public <T> CompletionStage<T> getOrElseUpdate(String key, Callable<CompletionStage<T>> block, int expiration) {
        return this.getOrElseUpdate(key, block);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> CompletionStage<T> getOrElseUpdate(String key, Callable<CompletionStage<T>> block) {
        final Object o = this.cache.get(key);
        if (Objects.isNull(o)) {
            try {
                return block.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture((T) o);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Done> set(String key, Object value, int expiration) {
        return this.set(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Done> set(String key, Object value) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> {
                this.cache.put(key, value);
                return Done.getInstance();
            }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Done> remove(String key) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> {
                this.cache.remove(key);
                return Done.getInstance();
            }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Done> removeAll() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            this.cache.clear();
            return Done.getInstance();
        });
    }
}
```